# Ampersand in python dont know what is wrong

Tags: python

I'm getting this error please help

```
    The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks       
("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

This is my code

```
import jwnet
import songList as sl
sl.downloadSongList(jwnet.ask("Name of your songlist "),
                    jwnet.ask("Output folder "))
```

I'm using custom libraries.
jwnet.ask is just like input = input("Question Here")
sl.downloadsonglist downloads a file from a txt

Comment: What are you using to run your code? Looks like an incorrect powershell command.

Comment: There is no ampersand in your code, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: vscode terminal

Comment: Can you show us the command you're actually using to execute the python in vscode terminal?

Comment: the custom library is on github if you need that source code

Comment: .& C:/Users/justk/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe d:/Code/Python/autodownload.py wait thats where the & is

Comment: removing that .& fixed it im so dumb sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check where your terminal is based.
You most likely have included an extra `&` in your code execution path.
e.g. &C:/Users/hello/...